# Return default value if there no result row in Joined table

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the explanation,
Master table:-

```
ID          |      col1
--------------------------
1                 value1
2                 value2
3                 value3
4                 value4
```

There is the secondary table called 'table1' and it is taking master table ID as a foreign key called Mapping_ID. But all the master table ID's are not available as Mapping_ID in table1.

```
Mapping_ID  |     message
--------------------------
1                 msg1
2                 msg2
4                 msg4
```

Please note that value 3 for Mapping_ID is not available. I want to make a view by joining those two tables and I want to replace a  default value called      'defaultMsg' to the message if there is no row in the table1 for a particular ID.

Output should be like as follows,

```
ID          |      col1       |    message
---------------------------------------------
1                 value1           msg1
2                 value2           msg2
3                 value3           Defaultmsg
4                 value4           msg4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Solution:

```
CREATE VIEW V1 (Id,col1,message)
AS SELECT m.Id,m.col1,COALESCE(t.message,'Defaultmsg') AS message
FROM Master m 
LEFT JOIN Table1 t
ON m.Id = t.Mapping_ID
ORDER BY m.ID;
```

Output:

```
ID  COL1    MESSAGE
1   value1  msg1
2   value2  msg2
3   value3  Defaultmsg
4   value4  msg4
```

Link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce905a/1

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` and `NVL` function to replace `NULL` value

```
-- left join demo
SELECT m.ID,m.col1,NVL(d.message,'Defaultmsg') message
FROM MASTER_TABLE m
LEFT JOIN DETAIL_TABLE d ON d.Mapping_ID=m.ID

-- right join demo
SELECT m.ID,m.col1,NVL(d.message,'Defaultmsg') message
FROM DETAIL_TABLE d
RIGHT JOIN MASTER_TABLE m ON d.Mapping_ID=m.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `left join` and `coalesce` to default null (no message) to 'Defaultmsg':

```
select m.id, m.col1, coalesce(t.message, 'Defaultmsg') as message
from master m
left join
table1 t
on m.id = t.mapping_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `coalesce`. It will return the value you give in the parameter in case the column is null.

[Oracle’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617)

Answer (score 1):

You could do that via `left joins` with `coalesce()` function

```
select m.id, m.col1, coalesce(t.message, 'Defaultmsg') message  
from Master m 
left join table1 t on t.Mapping_ID  = m.id
```

So, that you could create a view based on that

```
create view view_name as
select m.id, m.col1, coalesce(t.message, 'Defaultmsg') message  
from Master m 
left join table1 t on t.Mapping_ID  = m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a full outer join, using COALESCE:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TABLE1.ITEMID, TABLE2.ITEMID), COALESCE(VAL1, 0), COALESCE(VAL2, 0), 
    COALESCE(VAL3, 0), COALESCE(VAL4, 0), COALESCE(VAL5, 0)
FROM TABLE1 FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 
    ON TABLE1.ITEMID = TABLE2.ITEMID
```

The full outer join allows you to get data from both tables, even if there is no data in the first table.